# How to print floating point numbers as it is without any truncation in python?

Tags: python

I have some number 0.0000002345E^-60. I want to print the floating point value as it is.
What is the way to do it?
print %f truncates it to 6 digits.  Also %n.nf gives fixed numbers. What is the way to print without truncation.

Comment: How do you want it to be printed?

Comment: Not sure if a non-normalised scientific print is easily possible.

Comment: I want it to be printed as it is. Without any rounding off or truncation.

Comment: Can't you just print 60 0's and then the rest?

Comment: For your example, do you want to print 0.0000002345?????

Comment: It varies it can go up to e^ any value. It is not limited to 60. I could have done %60.60f.But I do not want it that way.

Comment: To make yourself clear, can you post an example of your input and expected output?

Comment: 1.4184031045858574E-61  this value should get printed as it it.Part after E is variable and has no fixed limit.

Comment: Since you're going against the conventions regarding leading zeros, I think you'll have to store the base and the exponent separately to get what you want.

Comment: Where are you getting the number from? If from file, you will have string which is not a problem. If from calculation, the representation doesn't matter. What is your scenario that makes this happen when you cannot represent this as the string before you do anything.

Answer (score 3):

Like this?

```
>>> print('{:.100f}'.format(0.0000002345E-60))
0.0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002344999999999999860343602938602754
```

As you might notice from the output, it’s not really that clear how you want to do it. Due to the float representation you lose precision and can’t really represent the number precisely. As such it’s not really clear where you want the number to stop displaying.

Also note that the exponential representation is often used to more explicitly show the number of [significant digits](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Significant_figures) the number has.

You could also use `decimal` to not lose the precision due to binary float truncation:

```
>>> from decimal import Decimal
>>> d = Decimal('0.0000002345E-60')
>>> p = abs(d.as_tuple().exponent)
>>> print(('{:.%df}' % p).format(d))
0.0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002345
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand, you want to print a float?

The problem is, you cannot print a float.

You can only print a string representation of a float. So, in short, you cannot print a float, that is your answer.

If you accept that you need to print a string representation of a float, and your question is how specify your preferred format for the string representations of your floats, then judging by the comments you have been very unclear in your question.

If you would like to print the string representations of your floats in exponent notation, then the format specification language allows this:

{:g} or {:G}, depending whether or not you want the E in the output to be capitalized). This gets around the default precision for e and E types, which leads to unwanted trailing 0s in the part before the exponent symbol.

Assuming your value is `my_float`, `"{:G}".format(my_float)` would print the output the way that the Python interpreter prints it. You could probably just print the number without any formatting and get the same exact result.

If your goal is to print the string representation of the float with its current precision, in non-exponentiated form, User [poke](https://stackoverflow.com/users/216074/poke) describes a good way to do this by casting the float to a Decimal object.

If, for some reason, you do not want to do this, you can do something like is mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3019027/791500). However, you should set 'max_digits' to `sys.float_info.max_10_exp`, instead of 14 used in the answer. This requires you to `import sys` at some point prior in the code.

A full example of this would be:

```
import math
import sys

def precision_and_scale(x):
    max_digits = sys.float_info.max_10_exp
    int_part = int(abs(x))
    magnitude = 1 if int_part == 0 else int(math.log10(int_part)) + 1
    if magnitude >= max_digits:
        return (magnitude, 0)
    frac_part = abs(x) - int_part
    multiplier = 10 ** (max_digits - magnitude)
    frac_digits = multiplier + int(multiplier * frac_part + 0.5)
    while frac_digits % 10 == 0:
        frac_digits /= 10
    scale = int(math.log10(frac_digits))
    return (magnitude + scale, scale)

f = 0.0000002345E^-60

p, s = precision_and_scale(f)

print "{:.{p}f}".format(f, p=p)
```

But I think the method involving casting to Decimal is probably better, overall.

Comment: Ok so if my variable m holds the value mentioned.How do I get the string in the form of .0003434E-56

Comment: You should never have a Python float value which displays as you have shown. Python (at least in the cPython 2.7.x for Windows) will display .0003434E-56 as 3.434E-60, which is equivalent and more compact.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`decimal.Decimal`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html):

```
>>> from decimal import Decimal
>>> str(Decimal(0.0000002345e-60))
'2.344999999999999860343602938602754401109865640550232148836753621775217856801120686600683401464097113374472942165409862789978024748827516129306833728589548440037314681709534891496105046826414763927459716796875E-67'
```

This is the actual value of `float` created by literal `0.0000002345e-60`. Its value is a number representable as python float which is closest to actual `0.0000002345 * 10**-60`.

`float` should be generally used for approximate calculations. If you want accurate results you should use something else, like mentioned `Decimal`.