# How to correctly detect data types in dask/pandas?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, machine-learning, dask, dask-dataframe

I'm currently loading a 4000 column csv into dask, doing some transformations and then converting it to Pandas.

By default all fields are loaded as float64, so a LOT of ram wasted and some dead kernels while experimenting.

Still using Pandas <1.0 for compatibility.

The question is, without downcasting (5 != 5.00), so maybe I can convert from float64 to float8, is there a way to make a massive detection of each column?
Setting from float to int8 it goes from 50gb df to 800MB aprox (yes, I'm destroying data, it was a test).

Huge dataframes are common in Machine Learning, I think there must be a standardized way to optimize them, no luck finding it...yet.

And after this conversion, to keep data types and persist the dataframe, is Parquet ok?

Thanks!!

Comment: if there are nulls, it will set to float. wont it?

Comment: There can be nulls in some (not all) columns, but for columns with a max value of 90.00 float64 sounds like a waste of RAM.

Comment: What about `float64` -> `float16`? I'm not sure exactly what your question is because you said you don't want to downcast, but your last sentence still mentions conversion.

Comment: You are right in this scenario, all data will be float, I mean don't change from float to int...yet, just want to automatically determine the lowest presicion I could set for each column. Question edited, Thanks!

Comment: Maybe can `apply` / `map` some of the ideas here: [determine-precision-and-scale-of-particular-number-in-python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3018758/determine-precision-and-scale-of-particular-number-in-python)

Comment: Will look into that, thanks! It look strange to me that this isn't a common problem or maybe I'm using the wrong. keywords, for ML, the dataframes can be huge and I can't find a standard optimization method. Thanks!